# Java Proguard and int comparator

Tags: java, proguard

I have a class that implements Compartor and it overrides the compare function:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ScoreComparator implements Comparator<Score> 
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Score s1, Score s2) 
    {
        return Integer.compare(s2.score, s1.score);
    }
}
```

When I compile using proguard I get the following error:

```
can't find referenced method 'int compare(int,int)' in class java.lang.Integer
You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
You may need to recompile them and try again.
Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
'-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
```

So I obviously added that option. However, I get the same error.

So what extra options should be added to the proguard config to eliminate this error?

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? Show us your code.

Comment: That's the error I'm getting... int compare(int, int)

Comment: What's your proguard configuration? In my tests, it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using Integer#compare(int,int), which only exists as of JDK 1.7. You should therefore also make sure that the Java runtime jar that you are specifying to ProGuard is the one from JDK 1.7.

Note: you seem to be specifying the Java runtime jar as a program jar (-injars). You probably want to specify it as a library jar (-libraryjars), so it doesn't end up as part of your application.